# tfsBuild throws exception when starting build, but still builds

Tags: exception, command-line, build, tfs, tfsbuild

I am creating a program to kick off builds for a series of projects.  I call a batch file from my code that starts the visual studio 2010 command prompt and executes various tfsbuild Start commands based on which project I select to build.  I specify the following arguments: TFSBuild start /collection:http://[myServer]:8080//builddefinition:"myProject/myBuildDefinition".  After executing the batch file I get the following error, but I go back into TFS and the build starts and succeeds.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.InformationNodeConverters.GetBuildSt
eps(IBuildInformation buildInformation)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.CommandLine.CommandStart.build_StatusChange
d(Object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.CommandLine.CommandStart.Run()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.CommandLine.BuildCommandLine.RunCommand(Str
ing commandName, String[] args, Boolean& showExitCode)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.CommandLine.RunCommand(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.CommandLine.Run(String[]& args)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.CommandLine.BuildCommandLine.Main(String[]
args)
```

Does anybody know of this issue?  Am I missing an argument when I call tfsBuild?

[C# code used]

```
private void _buildButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selectedProjectFolder.Equals("ProjectA"))
            Process.Start(@"N:\Build batch files\ProjectA_Build.bat");

        else if (_selectedProjectFolder.Equals("ProjectB"))
            Process.Start(@"N:\Build batch files\ProjectB_Build.bat");

        else if (_selectedProjectFolder.Equals("ProjectC"))
        {
            if (_build32RadioButton.Checked == true)
                Process.Start(@"N:\Build batch files\ProjectC_Build_32.bat");

            else if (_build64RadioButton.Checked == true)
                Process.Start(@"N:\Build batch files\ProjectC_Build_64.bat");
        }            
    }
```

[Batch file contents]

```
Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
TFSBuild start /collection:http://[MyServer]:8080/ /builddefinition:"MyProject/MyBuild"
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I added the code I use.

Comment: Post the entire C# code/method where you are calling the BAT file. I dont think it's anything to do with the bat file or the TFSBUILD start command. Its something within your C# code.

Comment: I posted the method.  As you see, the only thing I really use is Process.Start().  Also, I have tried just using the visual studio command prompt and I receive the same error.

Comment: I tried the command from the VS2010 command prompt and it worked like a charm. Are you running the command prompt as an admin?

Comment: I was not, but I just tried and received the same error.  Do you think it would matter that the project I am building uses .NET 2.0 and i'm building with the 2010 command prompt?

Comment: You said you are getting the same error while running the command on VS2010 command prompt?

Comment: Yes, the same error running as admin and not admin using VS2010 command prompt.

Comment: Can you check if you are gettign the same error while queuing the build from VS GUI? Team Explorer?

Comment: I just tried and I don't get an error when I queue a new build form VS GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the method "***InformationNodeConverters.GetBuildSteps(IBuildInformation)***" when it is talking to a newer version of the TFS server.

Note that buildsteps are no longer used after Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server and have been replaced with various new information node types, including IBuildMessage, IBuildError, IBuildWarning, and IActivityTracking. As a result, this method will typically return an empty list when talking to a server that is running a newer version (for example, Team Foundation Server 2010)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff734692(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, do you think there is anything I can do about this at its current state?

Comment: Am assuming you are using the old VS2008 build definitions right? Can you create a simple build definition in the VS2010 workflow and call it from your command line. Am hoping that it wont throw error.